# How to disable secure boot on acer aspire 5 running ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: boot, uefi, acer, bios

I can't disable the secure boot option on my acer laptop. It is greyed out. The boot mode is also set to UEFI which I cannot change as it is the only option. The laptop model is aspire 5 a515-52g-591j. Most of the BIOS option are greyed out, I have very little things I can change in there. I am at a loss.

Comment: Have tried customer support?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the BIOS password and then reboot.